# Forward-Slash missing from string in Sitecore Sublayout

Tags: c#, html, sitecore

I have a function in the C# code behind of a Sitecore sublayout that returns a string that looks like this:

```
public string getProductTitle() 
    {
        Item productItem = itemHelper.GetItemByPath(currentItemPath);
        Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField imgField = ((Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField)productItem.Fields["Logo"]);
        if (imgField.Value != "")
        {
            return "<sc:Image CssClass=\"product-image ng-scope\" Field=\"Logo\" runat=\"server\" />";
        }

        string productTitle = "";
        productTitle = productItem["Produkt Titel"];
        return "<div class=\"product-name ng-binding ng-scopen\" ng-if=\"!currentProduct.imageNameHome\">" + productTitle + "</div>";
    }
```

And in the ascx I call this fuction:

```
<%= getProductTitle() %>
```

The problem is that in the end this is what I'm getting in HTML at runtime:

```
"<sc:Image CssClass=\"product-image ng-scope\" Field=\"Logo\" runat=\"server\" >";
```

The / at the end is missing, which breaks the whole line and no image is shown. The

I also tried this:

```
string a = WebUtility.HtmlEncode("<sc:Image CssClass=\"product-image ng-scopen\" Field=\"Logo\" runat=\"server\" />");
return WebUtility.HtmlDecode(a);
```

and this:

```
return @"<sc:Image CssClass=""product-image ng-scopen"" Field=""Logo"" runat=""server"" />";
```

With the same result.

Am I missing something here? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have two alternate ways you wish to present your information, I would consider moving your controls and HTML to your markup file (ASCX) and then wrapping the segments in asp:placeholder controls.

```
<asp:placeholder id="imageTitle" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <sc:Image CssClass="product-image ng-scope" Field="Logo" runat="server" />
</asp:placeholder>
<asp:placeholder id="textTitle" runat="server>
    <div class="product-name ng-binding ng-scopen" ng-if="!currentProduct.imageNameHome">
       <asp:Literal id="productTitleLiteral" runat="server" />
    </div>;
</asp:placeholder>
```

You can then toggle the visibility of the placeholder in your code behind during page load.

```
public void Page_Load{
   Item productItem = itemHelper.GetItemByPath(currentItemPath);
   Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField imgField = ((Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField)productItem.Fields["Logo"]);
    if (imgField.Value != "")
    {
        this.imageTitle.Visible = true;
        this.textTitle.Visible = false;
    }
    else {
        this.imageTitle.Visible = false;
        this.textTitle.Visible = true;
        this.productTitleLiteral.Text = productItem["Produkt Titel"];
    }
}
```

This will allow you to ensure proper encapsulation of business logic versus presentation markup, and will work better with the .NET lifecycle.

Comment: I got this to work thanks to both of you. But now I've ran into another related problem: How would I use this inside a repeater? In the code behind I get the error message in the line **this.imageRelatedTitle.Visible = true;** that there's no definition for imageRelatedTitle. I have the asp:placeholder with this Id in a repeater.

Comment: Just figured it out: _var imageRelatedTitle = e.Item.FindControl("imageRelatedTitle") as PlaceHolder;_ in the ItemDataBound function.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see this working due to the ASP.NET page life cycle.

Sitecore controls are like normal user controls and they run on the server side - returning them as a string will be too late in the page lifecycle for them to render.

I would place the `<sc:Image />` control in the ascx page or use a `FieldRenderer` object to  get the HTML from Sitecore

```
 Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FieldRenderer.Render(myItem, "MyFieldName", "disable-web-editing=true");
```

You can then use logic to show or hide the Image Field  and title control based on you requirements. This assumes you are using the Sitecore Context Item.

Replace the `<%= getProductTitle() %>` with

```
 <sc:Image runat="server" ID="imgLogo" Field="Logo" />

 <asp:Placeholder runat="server" ID="phTitle">
   <div class=\"product-name ng-binding ng-scopen\" ng-if=\"!currentProduct.imageNameHome><sc:Text runat="server" ID="title"  Field="Produkt Titel"/></div>
 </asp:Placeholder>
```

Then in the code behind Page Load method

```
 var currentItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
 if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentItem["Logo"])
 {
    imgLogo.Visible=False;
 }

 if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentItem["Produkt Titel"])
 {
     phTitle.Visible=False;
 }
```

More information here:

http://gettingtoknowsitecore.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/displaying-field-values-using-server.html